# LongListSelector doesn't load all images

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I'm using LongListSelector with JumpListStyle, when I click on group header it opens list with headers (image + text), but last images aren't loading. Here is a image:

[image]

So how can I make LongListSelector to load all images ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this problem so this is a shot in the dark. If you swap Numbers with Family, is it then Family that doesn't have an image, or still Numbers?

Comment: In any case images for the last two items will not be loaded

Comment: give us a ground to start, show us your code

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently having the same problem ...

My JumpListStyle is an image.
The JumpList is in "List" mode, like you.

If I click on a header in the LongListSelector (with about 100 items) without scrolling all the list, the JumpList (containing 6 groups) is loading but with some images missing.
If I click on an JumpList item without image, and come back on the JumpList, the missing image is now loaded.
If I scroll all the LongListSelector items, the JumpList is ok now (all the images of the JumpList are loaded).

```
<Style x:Key="LongListSelectorJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
    <Setter Property="GridCellSize"  Value="111,111"/>
    <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="List" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="18,12,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource SVodBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2"    
                        Height="62" Width="286" Margin="20,20,20,20"                 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Visibility="{Binding EmptyGroup, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityInverseConverter}}">
                 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Visibility="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource ratingAvailableConverter}}" FontSize="30" Foreground="DarkGray" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource allRatingsConverter}}"/>
                        <Grid Visibility="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource ratingUnavailableConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
                             <TextBlock Text="?" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkGray" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I used ScrollTo method of LongListSelector to programmatically scroll down and up at first time when page loaded. It's working but not sure it is right way.